Cypress Azure Active Directory React
I am having troubles when trying to run the cypress in my gitlab ci. Locally when I try to run my tests via the cypress open or run commands everything seems to work smoothly.
The thing that primarily causes the errors is the initial pop up which sometimes states that the user needs to log out. Locally, it redirects to the login page. In order for this to happen the cy.wait(1000) found in the beginning of the code is necessary. I didn't find this though in the official documentation
You may see that in the CI Pipeline I even wait for 4000ms 
In the cypress/support/e2e.js file I have the following code that runs before every test
function loginViaAAD(username, password) {
  cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/');

  // Sometimes the tests opens the "Logout" page, but if we wait
  // it goes away and loads the log in page automatically
  cy.wait(1000);


  // Login to your AAD tenant.
  cy.origin(
    'login.microsoftonline.com',
    {
      args: {
        username,
      },
    },
    ({ username }) => {
      cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(username, {
        log: false,
      });
      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click();
    },
  );

  // depending on the user and how they are registered with Microsoft, the origin may go to live.com
  cy.origin(
    'login.microsoftonline.com',
    { args: { password } },
    ({ password }) => {
      cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(password, { log: false });
      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click();
      cy.wait(2000);
    },
  );

  cy.origin('login.microsoftonline.com', () => {
    cy.task('generateOTP').then((otp) => {
      // Enter OTP
      cy.get('#idTxtBx_SAOTCC_OTC').type(otp);
      cy.get('#idSubmit_SAOTCC_Continue').click();
      cy.wait(2000);

      // case where the pop up appears with the "Stay signed in" message
      cy.get('body').then((body) => {
        if (body.find('#KmsiCheckboxField')) {
          cy.get('#KmsiCheckboxField').click(); // checkbox
          cy.get('#idSIButton9').click(); // yes button
          cy.wait(2000);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}


Cypress.Commands.add('loginToAAD', (username, password) => {
  cy.session(
    `AAD-${username}`,
    () => {
      const log = Cypress.log({
        displayName: 'Azure Active Directory Login',
        message: [`Authenticating | ${username}`],
        autoEnd: false,
      });

      log.snapshot('before');

      loginViaAAD(username, password);

      log.snapshot('after');
      log.end();
    },
    {
      validate: () => {
        // this is a very basic form of session validation.
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000');
        cy.get('.header__avatar-name').should(
          'contain',
          `${Cypress.env('AAD_FULLNAME')}`,
        );
      },
    },
  );
});

before(() => {
  cy.log(Cypress.env('AAD_USERNAME'));
  // log into Azure Active Directory through our sample SPA using our custom command
  cy.loginToAAD(Cypress.env('AAD_USERNAME'), Cypress.env('AAD_PASSWORD'));
  cy.visit('http://localhost:3000');
});

That is my CI Job
e2e-tests:
  image: cypress/browsers:node-20.14.0-chrome-126.0.6478.114-1-ff-127.0.1-edge-126.0.2592.61-1
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
  script:
    - npm run linux_start &
    - npx cypress run --browser chrome --env AAD_USERNAME=$AAD_USERNAME,AAD_FULLNAME=$AAD_FULLNAME,AAD_PASSWORD=$AAD_PASSWORD,TOTP_SECRET=$TOTP_SECRET
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - cypress/videos/**/*.mp4
      - cypress/screenshots/**/*.png
    expire_in: 1 day

Ignore in the CI that the env variables seem to be undefined.

It is possible that the cy.wait() command is not enough to ensure that the pop-up disappears and the login page is loaded in the CI pipeline. In the CI job, the cy.wait() command is set to 4000ms, which is longer than the 1000ms used locally. It may be worth experimenting with different wait times to see if this resolves the issue.

@Rukmini I did play around with the wait values but still, I could not fix it. I even wrote an assertion to try and find the "Logout" button while still being at localhost:3000 but it still doesn't seem to work. I am currently experimenting with re-directions. Quite frustrating.

@Rukmini I found the solution... I forgot to pass the env variables. Thus the msalConfig was misconfigured. Also the password for the OTP contained symbols and GitLab didn't like it.
